# Conditionally add where to the statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writiting a store procedure.

This procedure is getting 4 arguments which will be used in `where` clause. Problem is that these parameters can be empty.

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
select * from Books
If(@param1 <> "")
add where title =@param1 
to the clause
```

But I have no idea how to make it. Is it even possible?

Comment: `WHERE (Field=@Param OR @Param IS NULL) AND (Otherfield=@Otherparam OR @Otherparam IS NULL)` etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of query is called [catch-all-query](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/). There are several ways to do this, one of which is using combinations of`AND` and `OR` conditions:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Books
    WHERE
        (@param1 = '' OR title = @param1)
```

Another way is to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Books WHERE 1 = 1'

IF @param1 <> '' BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND title = @param1'
END

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @sql,
    N'@param1 VARCHAR(10)',
    @param1 = @param1
```

Additional reading:

- Erland Sommarskog's article on [dynamic search conditions.](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
Select * from Books where (Title=@title or @title='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Books
where (title = @param or @param = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want handle null in your parameter and want to include records where there is a null in the title field you can  use

```
select *
from Books
where ISNULL(title,#)=ISNULL(@param,#)
```

Comment: I will not prefer this method. This makes the query **non-sargable**

Comment: @MotoGP Its up to the requirement.There are multiple ways doing the same thing,you can also optimize this one as well.